# Pass variables to Tornado base templates

Tags: python, tornado

I have a base template base.html from which other templates inherit from.

After a user logs on I want to display their userID on navigation bar defined in base.html

So I have:

```
class CloseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):   
    def get(self):       
        ui=db.users.find_one({"Username": ui0})        
        self.render("thanks.html" , ui1 = ui["Username"])
```

I also want to display the value of ui1 in the base template as: `<p>{{ ui1 }}</p>`

The only way round this is to move my navigation bar html code from base.html and insert it into every other template.

I however get this error:

```
 NameError: global name 'ui1' is not defined
```

I've tried setting this as a global variable but it still gives the same error.

How could variables be used in different templates then?

Comment: can you post your contents of `base.html` and `thanks.html`?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I recommend creating a base class, that your handlers extend:

`class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):`. This will allow you to add functions available to all your handlers.

Next  you can extend the [`tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_namespace()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_namespace) function, and add your global variables to the namespace:

```
# class BaseHandler
def get_template_namespace(self):
    namespace = super(BaseHandler, self).get_template_namespace()
    namespace.update({
        'username': self.get_current_username() # or however you retrieve users
    })
    return namespace
```

Everything passed to the namespace is provided to `self.render` in all your handlers.

Now you can access `{{ username }}` in either base.html or the view extending it.